# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PointerTemplateUtility.exe

Tags: c#-3.0

Exception is popping in below code under:- "DataSet ds = new DataSet();"

```
public DataSet GetCommandResponse(int ID)
{
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("WEB_GetInOutMsgHandlerResponse");
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
 ds = GenericStatementReturnDataSet(cmd, ds, "Unable to fetch template ID");
 return ds;
}
```

It works fine in Most of the time without exception in sometime it throws an exception

Comment: Can you show me full page code? I think this error will occurred when we will call recurring call.

Comment: Full page code flows from different class.

Comment: U r right...i m using a recursive function,it works,but sometime it gives me an exception

Comment: Without showing full code how can I jug where problem is? Displayed code does not any issue.